# GraphicsMagick outputs empty file

Tags: graphicsmagick

While trying to figure out why my output images from my node applications are not functioning currently, I decided to try the GraphicsMagick GUI.

On a windows 7 pro 64x I open the gm gui, and opened one of the windows default images.

[image: Image in GM]

Then, without performing any operations on it, I just saved it under a different filename: "test.jpg"

Save prompts no errors.

Now, when I go to the saved file. I get no thumbnail for it:
[image: No thumbnail for file]

When I try to open the file, I get the following error: 
[image: Error from gm]

I tried googling this error to no avail. 
Something is broken when I save my file in gm. 
Note: This problem does no occur with ImageMagick.

I tried installing multiple versions and releases of GM. None work.

I am running a windows 7 pro x64 with 64gb ram, and dual cpu (have no idea is that's relevant).

Also, how can I check if this is a permissions issue? The user running this app has administrator permissions, but.. maybe something get's broken?

As you can see i'm completely at a loss.

Comment: The permission would forbid the creation of the file, empty or not. Did you try with an other file format ?

Comment: tried jpg and png

Comment: You could try running GM by the command line to see if provides some output/debug/options.

Comment: It does not. Additionally, running it from node (with a error handler setup) never triggers the error handler. In fact, gm thinks he executed the action correctly